# how do I pass a reference to an object via button_click in WPF/C#

Tags: c#, wpf, pass-by-reference

I have two pages in WPF.  Page A contains all of my code.  Page B is meant to be like a control panel where I click buttons to operate window A.

The problem I am running into is I want to make function calls from B to A but I am getting a scope error.

In the below code I am getting the error specifically on the axFlash object.

```
namespace GoogleMapsFlashInWpf
```

{

```
public partial class ButtonPage : Page
{
    public ButtonPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ClearMarkersButton(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StackTrace asdf = new StackTrace();
        Console.WriteLine(asdf.GetFrame(0).GetMethod().Name.ToString() + " called from " + asdf.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name.ToString());
        XElement call = new XElement("invoke",
                new XAttribute("name", "clearMarkers"),
                new XAttribute("returntype", "xml"));
        try
        {

            axFlash.CallFunction(call.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting));
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(error.ToString());
        }

    }//end ClearMarkersButton
}
```

}

Comment: What's axFlash? Where's your other class? What error are you getting, exactly?

Comment: You will need to provide a bit more information. What kind of error are you getting? And what type of object is axFlash?

Comment: axFlash is a flash object.  I am getting this error: "Error 1 The name 'axFlash' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: @Paul: So where *is* `axFlash` declared?

Comment: @Jon Skeet: it is declared in the first window's code which I have not posted.

Comment: @Paul: So how did you expect that to work? Do you have a reference to an instance of the first window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is right...the axFlash object doesn't exist in the scope of that method. You need to make axFlash an object defined under ButtonPage class. Then, you must make sure that  axFlash object is set before you wish to call that function.

Comment: I would ideally like to just call the method located in window A.  How would I do this?

Comment: To do that, you should first add a definition of window A in window B. Then, in window B, within your code, call Parent.axFlash.CallFunction.

Note that axFlash must be visible to the outside world.